# Visual Studio memory leak detection not working

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, memory-leaks, profiler

I am trying to use the C++ [memory leak detection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5at7yxcs.aspx) in Visual Studio 2008, but it does not work because I always get these two failures:

1. `error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int`
2. `error C2365: '_CrtSetDbgFlag' : redefinition; previous definition was 'function'`

I had tried putting this at the top of certain code files:

```
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>
_CrtSetDbgFlag ( _CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF );
```

I do not understand which source/header files this is supposed to go in however, as the documentation for how to use this seems poor.  It is for a CPython extension with numerous CPP/H files.  Should these four lines go at the top of each and every code file?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can place it in the project #defines, that way it is defined *everywhere*

Answer (score 1):

You can't *call* a function in the global scope, you need to put the function call in the `main` function.